# Change dataframe values avobe and below a cell with a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column called "flag" with values 1 and 0. 1 means that the data is alright and 0 that there was something weird with this data value. I want to create another column called "safe" that copies the flag values value and changes to 0 a N number of cells above and below a 0 value in "flag". For example with N=2 I want to get this output:

```
  flag safe
1   1   1
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   0   0
5   1   0
6   1   0
7   1   1
8   1   0
9   1   0
10  0   0
11  0   0
12  1   0
13  1   0
14  1   1
15  1   1
```

I want to be able to change N=3,4,5,6 manually so I can see how big is the impact. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) + [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) and [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
N=2
df['safe'] = (df['flag'].where(lambda x: x.eq(0))
                        .bfill(limit=N)
                        .ffill(limit=N)
                        .fillna(df['flag'], downcast='int'))
print(df)
```

---

```
    flag  safe
1      1     1
2      1     0
3      1     0
4      0     0
5      1     0
6      1     0
7      1     1
8      1     0
9      1     0
10     0     0
11     0     0
12     1     0
13     1     0
14     1     1
15     1     1
```

---